# Error Objective C forControlEvents

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am new to objective C and am having a problem with the following line. The error is: "Passing argument 3 of 'addTarget;action:forControlEvents:' makes integer from pointer without a cast." The wierd thing is that I get the warnings and everything works fine on the IPAD but on the simulator it works sometimes and other times it does not work. I have a textfield in a tableviewcell, when the user types it sends what they typed to a variable.

```
[textField addTarget:self  action:@selector(setFilterCriteria:)  forControlEvents:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification];
```

Here is the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)setFilterCriteria:(id)sender {
    UITextField *senderTextField = (UITextField *)sender;
    appDelegate.setFilterCriteria = senderTextField.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong kind of thing for the control event.

`UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` is a notification name, not a control event type. You want one of the `UIControlEvent...` constants, like `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

(You're seeing the warning because the notification names are NSString*s, and the expected type of that argument is a defined numeric constant.)

Comment: The strange part is if I use UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification the action fires on the IPad but not on the simulator. If I use UIControlEventValueChanged I don't get the warnings but the action never fires. If I change it back to UITextFieldDidChangeNotification the app works fine I just get the warnings and the simulator still doesn't fire the action.

Comment: So I found several other people using the UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification but having sporatic issues as I as I did. I finally changed the last part from "forControlEvents:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" to "forControlEvents:UIContolEventEditingChanged" this event seems to fire the action. For some reason the "forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged" didn't do anything. Now my warnings are gone and the event fires on IPAD and Simulator.